# How to select a specific color in Photoshop CS2?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, cs2

I'm trying to reduce colors from million to 7 exact colors. It's a fabric design, so I want to separate greens from the other colors. However, when I want to pick greens, other different colored pixels that belong to motifs are getting included in the selection area.

Comment: Have you tried using photoshop's "select color range" tool?

Comment: yes i have tried it, but it didn't work at all. my goal is to reduce colors by their own values. for example; i want to obtain only greens in leaf motifs. but when i reduce the color, i see some greens, blues, and yellows in a leaf. because i also used that colors in the whole design.

Comment: Is Photoshop CS2 not a little bit old?

Comment: @Kurt If that's what the OP has to work with...

Comment: @Kurt You are right, but the company I work for has only this version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news.... yes, it can be done in practically *any* version of Photoshop.

The bad news.... It can be a difficult task depending upon the artwork. In addition, to requiring some experience with creating selections and masks.

Trying to remember CS2: `Select > Color Range...` may possibly get a good starting selection, as mentioned in the comments above.

`Quick Mask` would allow you to "paint" areas you want to be part of a selection.

You could use the `Channels Panel` combined with tools such as the Magic Wand to get a selection.

And of course, there's the Magic Wand tool or Pen tool or Lasso tool to draw a selection.

There are a great many methods to create a selection. Essentially just use whatever is easiest for you to get a good *starting* selection. No method is just going to be "perfect" with a click. What you describe *"other different colored pixels get selected"* is due to anti-aliasing. This is going to happen with practically any selection method if the artwork has anti-aliasing. There's no way to easily or automatically get around anti-aliasing in most cases.

After a selection is created, it's a matter of refinement. Once you have a selection, turn it into a layer mask. Once you have a layer mask, you can then go in and manually use a brush to paint away any anti-aliasing pixels you do not want as part of the selection.

Basically the procedure would be the same as removing a background from an image but in this case you'd be removing everything *except* the color you want to retain.

Seeing a screen shot of *specific* artwork may yield more detailed instructions. However, in most case the above steps are pretty much the same.